# How to instantiate new Kotlin class

Tags: class, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and I am struggling with classes.
Lets say I have a class called player, we'll keep it simple:

```
class Player (var name: String)
```

What I want to do is have a button that when clicked will create a new player. I understand onClickListener etc for a button and I know to populate the class I can do something like:

```
var playerOne = Player("John")
```

what I don't understand is how to create a playerTwo or a second instance of the class Player on a button click.
Obviously `var playerTwo = Player("Mike")` would work, but how do I get that to change when the button is pressed a second, or third or tenth time?

This may seem very obvious to some people but I am very new and I'm just not sure what to be searching for and I have spent a long time looking for an answer.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciate!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `var playerOne.Player("John")`? This is not valid Kotlin syntax. Do you mean `var playerOne = Player("John")`?

Comment: And then `var playerTwo = Player("Mary")`

Comment: I think you want a list of players. `val players = mutableListOf<Player>(); players += Player("John"); players += Player("Mike")`

Comment: @m0skit0 your right, I should have taken more time in writing that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that looks like it might be Java, but that gives me something to look into. I'm still not sure how to implement that into a button click (sorry, very new at this).
Thanks for your response, at least I now have something to Google.

Comment: It doesn't work as Java, it's idiomatic Kotlin. The `;` is needed when you put everything on one line, consequence of the comment format.

Comment: `override fun onClick(e: Event) { players += Player("John") }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thank you, I will give this a go when I get the chance.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I assume this would work if the class has multiple properties (e.g. name, age, score etc) ? and then how would I access those properties for each player later?

Comment: You can access those properties later from the `players` list that you have defined earlier. You are just adding new `Player` to the `players` list on every click. Accessing properties of every player would be just by accessing the corresponding player from the list and then accessing the property required.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.onClickListener = { this.player = Player("...")}
```

Do I understand your question right?

Comment: Possibly, I'm don't completely understand your answer though. It is the 'this' part I'm unsure of. What happens when that view is clicked multiple times?

Comment: `this.player` is meant to be a reassignment of object's property, I did not make actual accent on this. The accent here is in update "on a button click"